# Как реализовать следующий запрос, написанный на MySql, только на PostgreSql?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Исходная выборка отсортирована по возрастанию по `ID_1` и `ID_2`.
`ID_2` всегда больше `ID_1`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо получить такую выборку, где в самом результате `ID_1` одной записи будет больше чем `ID_2` предыдущей записи. Всегда берем первые подходящие записи.
Т.е., для приведенной выборки результат будет следующим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На MySql запрос будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
SET @last = 0;
SELECT `ID_1`, @last := `ID_2` AS `ID_2`
  FROM (  

      SELECT `ID_1`, `ID_2` 
      FROM `test`
      ORDER BY `ID_1`, `ID_2`
  ) AS `t`
  WHERE `ID_1` > @last;
```

Как такой запрос реализовать на PostgreSql?

Answer (score 1):

Пока только рекурсией получилось:

```
with recursive Q as(
  (select id_1, id_2, cast(1 as bigint) as RN
     from test order by id_1, id_2 limit 1)
 union all
  select N.id_1, N.id_2, row_number() over (order by N.id_1, N.id_2) RN
    from Q, test N where N.id_1 > Q.id_2 and Q.RN=1
)
select id_1, id_2
  from Q where RN=1
```